# Is there any way to highlight a line of code in Confluence code block?

Tags: confluence

Using Confluence and using the code block macro and the engineer would like to highlight a line of code. The tools up top are grayed out once I am inside the macro. How can I apply a yellow highlight or bold to text when inside the code block macro?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't (AFAIK). However, you could try adding comments inside the code. For example, if the code is

```
int myVar = 5;
myVar = myVar * myVar;
```

and your engineer would like to highlight `myVar = myVar * myVar;`, you can edit the macro to look like this:

```
int myVar = 5;

//
// !IMPORTANT
//
myVar = myVar * myVar;
```

or, more elegantly

```
int myVar = 5;
myVar = myVar * myVar; // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

However, the comment symbols might change from programming language to programming language, so consult with the engineer what style would be appropriate.